# What is the difference between position() and rposition() for rust iterators and is there any reason for it?

Tags: rust, iterator

So I was browsing through the iterator functions (because they are cool) and I noticed that there were two functions that seemed to do the exact same thing except one takes an `ExactSizeIterator`
and other doesn't.

What would be the use case of using one function over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `position` starts at the beginning, and goes forward until it finds a matching element, and returns its position. This doesn't require knowing how many elements there are in total, hence `Iterator` is enough.
- `rposition` starts at the end, and goes backward until it finds a matching element, and returns its position (from the beginning!). Because the position is returned from the beginning of the iterator (think of it as being usable as a slice index), it needs to know exactly how many elements there are in the iterator, hence `ExactSizeIterator` is required.

Comment: Ah so thats what the `r` stands for! Thanks : )